# C Reading negative and positive numbers from file into Array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I want to read numbers from a file, each number is on a new line and they are decimal numbers, some of them are negative  numbers. I want to store them into an array and count how many numbers are in the file.
I know the following code counts the numbers, but it only counts the positive numbers in the file. I've tried changing '0' to a negative value but they doesn't work, it doesn't give errors but it always doesn't give the correct output. How can I count negative and positive numbers?

```
 int main()
    {
            double a[MAX];
            double num;
            int n = 0;

            scanf("%lf", &num);
            while (num >=0) {
                a[n] = num;
                n++;
                scanf("%lf", &num);
            }
    }
```

Comment: `while (n < MAX && scanf("%lf", &num) == 1) { a[n++] = num; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You will break the loop as soon as you find the first non-positive number. Also, you are not making sure that you don't use `a` out of bounds. You need to use:

```
while ( n < MAX && scanf("%lf", &num) == 1 )
{
   if ( num >= 0 )
   {
      a[n] = num;
      n++;
   }
}
```

If you want to count all non-zero numbers, use:

```
while ( n < MAX && scanf("%lf", &num) == 1 )
{
   if ( num != 0 )
   {
      a[n] = num;
      n++;
   }
}
```

Since you will be reading the numbers in the conditional of the `while` loop, remove the `scanf` line before the loop.

Comment: @EbonyDoe, since you accepted my answer, I am assuming that you don't need any more clarifications. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (num >=0)
```

This loop condition will break as soon as you read a negative number. You can end the loop as soon as there is no more numbers in the file to read, and count the number of positive in the process:

```
int main()
{
        double a[MAX];
        double num;
        int n = 0;

        while (n < MAX && scanf("%lf", &num) == 1) {
            a[n] = num;
            n++;
        }

        // to count positives, zeros, negatives
        int np, nz, ng;
        np = nz = ng = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] > 0) np++;
            else if (a[i] == 0) nz++;
            else ng++;
        }
        printf("%d %d %d\n", np, nz, ng);
}
```